# Whenever I try to rotate imageview, it only rotates on axis

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, gesture

So I have been attempting to create a program that can drag, zoom and rotate a photo. The big problem I seem to be running into is that whenever I try to rotate the photo, it rotates along the corner, rather than around the center. This means that as I try to rotate the image, it quickly leaves my fingers.

Another big problem I have is that every time I touch with two fingers, the image resets to being perfectly upright, instead of the angle it held when i touched it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.save();
    //if(mode==DRAG)
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    if (myScale.isInProgress()) {
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, myScale.getFocusX(), myScale.getFocusY());
    }
    else{
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mLastGestureX, mLastGestureY);
    }

    if (myScale.isInProgress()) {
        canvas.rotate(degrees, myScale.getFocusX(), myScale.getFocusY());
    }
    else{
        canvas.rotate(degrees, mLastGestureX, mLastGestureY);
    }
    //canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    //setImageMatrix(matrix);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    //canvas.drawBitmap(,matrix,new Paint());
}













@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if(event.getPointerCount()>1){

        myScale.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);

                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                mode=DRAG;
                // Remember where we started
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            //savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            //midPoint(mid, event);
            Log.d("touchResponse: ", "mode=ZOOM");
            final float gx = myScale.getFocusX();
            final float gy = myScale.getFocusY();
            mLastGestureX=gx;
            mLastGestureY=gy;
            mode=ZOOM;
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        }


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);


                // Calculate the distance moved

            if(!myScale.isInProgress()&&mode==DRAG){
                    // Move the object
                float dx = x-mLastTouchX;
                float dy = y-mLastTouchY;
                    mPosX+=dx;
                     mPosY+=dy;


                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event


                    // Invalidate to request a redraw
                    invalidate();

            }
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                if(event.getPointerCount()==2){
                    if (lastEvent!=null){
                    newRot=rotation(event);
                    degrees = newRot-d;

                    }

                }
                invalidate();
                break;

            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

        }


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor\
            mode=NONE;
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            final int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            invalidate();

            break;
        }

        }

    return true;
}
















//this is a method i ripped from a tutoriaql
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}



private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));


        //matrix=temp;

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    //if (Constant.TRACE) Log.d("Rotation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", delta_x+" ## "+delta_y+" ## "+radians+" ## "
    //        +Math.toDegrees(radians));
    Log.d("Rotation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", delta_x+" ## "+delta_y+" ## "+radians+" ## "
            +Math.toDegrees(radians));
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate around the center, you need to translate to the center first.  That will set the new origin as the center of the image, and rotate always rotates around the origin.